# Tengo un problema con menú Switch en listas Enlazadas en C

Tags: c, lista

tengo este problema el cual es que al momento de crear un menu con Switch por ejemplo en la opcion 1, para agregar elementos a la lista, solo almacena el ultimo nodo y el resto los elimina, es como si estuviera reiniciando la Lista, al final tengo un codigo estatico agregando elementos a la lista e imprimiendolos y funciona perfectamente, pero al hacerlo en el switch no, algun error que no vea? soy muy nuevo en C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAM_MAXIMO 80

typedef struct nodo
{
    char *contenido;
    struct nodo *sig;
} Contenido;

Contenido *listaContenido(Contenido *Lista)
{
    Lista = NULL;
    return Lista;
}

Contenido *agregarContenido(Contenido *Lista, char *contenido)
{
    Contenido *nuevoContenido, *aux;
    nuevoContenido = (Contenido *)malloc(sizeof(Contenido));
    nuevoContenido->contenido = contenido;
    nuevoContenido->sig = NULL;
    if (Lista == NULL)
    {
        Lista = nuevoContenido;
    }
    else
    {
        aux = Lista;
        while (aux->sig != NULL)
        {
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        aux->sig = nuevoContenido;
    }
    return Lista;
}

typedef struct nodo2
{
    char *email;
    struct nodo2 *sig;
    struct nodo *listaMsj;
} Email;

Email *listaEmail(Email *Lista)
{
    Lista = NULL;
    return Lista;
}

Email *agregarEmail(Email *Lista, char *email, Contenido *listaMsj)
{
    Email *nuevoEmail, *aux;
    nuevoEmail = (Email *)malloc(sizeof(Email));
    nuevoEmail->email = email;
    nuevoEmail->listaMsj = listaMsj;
    nuevoEmail->sig = NULL;
    if (Lista == NULL)
    {
        Lista = nuevoEmail;
    }
    else
    {
        aux = Lista;
        while (aux->sig != NULL)
        {
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        aux->sig = nuevoEmail;
    }
    return Lista;
}

int verificarEmail(Email *Lista, char *email)
{
    Email *aux;
    int a = -1;
    if (Lista == NULL)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        aux = Lista;
        while (aux != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(aux->email, email) == 0)
            {
                a = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                a = -1;
            }
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        return a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int opcion;
    char email[TAM_MAXIMO], email2[TAM_MAXIMO], email3[TAM_MAXIMO];
    int res = 0;
    Email *Lista = listaEmail(Lista);
    Contenido *ListaMsj = listaContenido(ListaMsj);

    do
    {
        printf("\t\n==== Menu ====\n");
        printf("1.- Regitrar Usuario \n2.- Enviar un correo electrÃ³nico ");
        printf("\n3.- Solicitar un correo electrÃ³nico \n4.- Salir \n");
        scanf("%d", &opcion);

        switch (opcion)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Ingrese el nuevo e-mail: ");
            scanf("%s", email);            
            if (verificarEmail(Lista, email) != 1)
            {
                Lista = agregarEmail(Lista, email, ListaMsj);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Correo ya registrado");
            }

            Lista = agregarEmail(Lista, email, ListaMsj);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Ingrese su e-mail: ");
            scanf("%s", email2);
            printf("lista a ver: " + verificarEmail(Lista, email2));
            if (verificarEmail(Lista, email2) == 1)
            {
                printf("Ingrese el destinatario: ");
                scanf("%s", email3);

                if (verificarEmail(Lista, email3) == 1)
                {
                    while (Lista != NULL)
                    {
                        if (strcmp(Lista->email, email3) == 0)
                        {
                            char conte;
                            printf("Ingrese el mensaje: ");
                            scanf("%s", &conte);
                            Lista->listaMsj = agregarContenido(ListaMsj, &conte);
                            break;
                        }
                        Lista = Lista->sig;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Correo del destinatario no registrado");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Correo no registrado");
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            while (Lista != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s\n", Lista->email);
                Contenido *listaC = Lista->listaMsj;
                while (listaC != NULL)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", listaC->contenido);
                    listaC = listaC->sig;
                }
                Lista = Lista->sig;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            res = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("default\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (res != 1); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Y esta es la parte que hice estáticamente y funciona perfectamente

```
        Email *Lista = listaEmail(Lista);
        Contenido *ListaMsj = listaContenido(ListaMsj);
        ListaMsj = agregarContenido(ListaMsj, "Mensaje 1");
        ListaMsj = agregarContenido(ListaMsj, "Mensaje 2");
    
        Contenido *ListaMsj2 = listaContenido(ListaMsj2);
        ListaMsj2 = agregarContenido(ListaMsj2, "Mensaje 333");
        ListaMsj2 = agregarContenido(ListaMsj2, "Mensaje 444");
        ListaMsj2 = agregarContenido(ListaMsj2, "Mensaje 555");
        ListaMsj2 = agregarContenido(ListaMsj2, "Mensaje 66");
    
        Lista = agregarEmail(Lista, "luis@gmail.com", ListaMsj);
        Lista = agregarEmail(Lista, "allen@gmail.com", ListaMsj2); 
        
        while (Lista != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", Lista->email);
            Contenido *listaC = Lista->listaMsj;
            while (listaC != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s\n", listaC->contenido);
                listaC = listaC->sig;
            } 
            Lista = Lista->sig;
        }
```

Les agradezco toda respuesta